# vagrant box add vs. vagrant init?

Tags: vagrant

I'm reading the [Vagrant docs on boxes](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/boxes.html) and not understanding the difference between:

- `vagrant box add hashicorp/precise32`; vs.
- `vagrant init hashicorp/precise32`

The latter fetches the `hashicorp/precise32` box from a remote catalog, and then creates a `Vagrantfile` for spinning up an instance of that box. But I don't see how that's different than the `box add` method.

So I ask: **What's the difference between these two commands and when is it appropriate to use each of them?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`vagrant box add` would just add the box and don't create a `Vagrantfile`. That's it.

I'm always using `vagrant init boxname boxurl`, but there might be use cases where you don't want to place a Vagrantfile. Let's say you want to add a couple of images in a loop for example.

Comment: Thanks @hek2mgl (+1) - but when you say "**`vagrant box add` would just add the box...", I'm still not understanding! Add the box...to **what?!?** In other words, what is different about your local file system/machine *after* running `vagrant box add` then before? Thanks agaiN!

Comment: box in `vagrant box` means *base box*. You need only one *base box* of a certain OS image but you can create multiple instances of it - without need to download the base image again. An instance you are creating using `vagrant init`. (plus `vagrant up`).

Comment: Ahhh ok thanks @hek2mgl (+1 again) - can you just confirm this: that both commands add "boxes" under your (in the case of Virtual Box) `~/VirtualBox VMs/` directory, however, `vagrant init` actually creates a `Vagrantfile` for you? If that is correct, then I see what you mean: why ever use `box add`? Why would you ever want a box but not a `Vagrantfile` for it? Thanks again!

Comment: Let's say, it doesn't hurt to have it. You are welcome.

Comment: Really late to the party: I want to pre-populate on a deployed system the basic type of vagrant instance I'm going to use.  I intend to run many simultaneous vagrant instances of this same type.  I do `vagrant box` to get it populated on my system and take the download hit upfront rather than the first time I call `vagrant init` for it.

Comment: @smeeb I think VagrantFile contains configs such as folders that should be mapped,  sites virtual hosts and where they should be pointed. The VagrantFile can be added to git repository to share common environment between developers

Answer (score 1):

```
vagrant box add hashicorp/precise32
```

just download the box image into your vagrant application
while:

```
vagrant init hashicorp/precise32
```

make a vagrant file in current directory.
if vagrant box image hasn`t been downloaded before. then it try to download the vagrant box image.

in the scenario which vagrant box has been added then we want to init a vagrant file.
in shell we can get an name auto complete with Tab button, because it knows the vagrant image already.